# Select rows in a table where id is equals to another id in another table

Tags: mysql

I would like to select a certain row in my getadvocacy table where id is the id in another table called swimsuit.

**swimsuit table**

```
id         |         name          |       average
1          |         Abc           |       90
3          |         Def           |       99
```

**getadvocacy**

```
id         |        all_scores     |       average_score
1          |        70,70,70       |       70
2          |        70,70,70       |       70
3          |        70,70,70       |       70
```

Now, I want to select from getadvocacy but only 1 and 3 because it is the data on swimsuit.

**Expected Output**

```
id         |        all_scores     |       average_score
1          |        70,70,70       |       70
3          |        70,70,70       |       70
```

I tried this but it has different output.

```
select getadvocacy.id, all_scores, average_score from getadvocacy WHERE getadvocacy.id IN (select id from swimsuit)
```

Comment: What do you mean with *didn't work*: did you get an error? Did you get a different result? Could you clarify this?

Comment: getting different result. sorry. i'll edit it.

Comment: I put your question in a fiddle, and it *does* give the desired output: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63069/1. What are you not telling us?

Comment: I don't think the chosen answer is the right one, I explained why in a comment there, too. The join can produce more copy of getadvocacy records if the column id admits duplicates for the table swimsuit. Also if it gives you the expected result with your specific data, it doesn't mean the approach is right. If you want to check the existence of a tuple in a table the proper way is to use "in" operator or "exists" operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the id (primary key) is same for table then you can use join on Id

```
 select * from table1
        JOIN table2 
             on table1.id = table2.id
```

Use this

```
  select * from swimsuit JOIN getadvocacy ON swimsuit.id= getadvocacy.id;
```

Result of query is

```
    1   abc 90  1   50,60,70    70
    3   def 99  3   60,70,70    70
```

Comment: I think this is not the right approach, because if table2 has more rows for some id of table1 you will get more copy of the corresponding records, the standard way is to use "in" operator.

Comment: The thing is that the OP already had correct code. @SeeMore, could you comment on this?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest and easier to understand: 
Just by reading between the lines, you will understand how this snippet works

```
SELECT getadvocacy.* , swimsuittable.*
FROM getadvocacy, swimsuittable
WHERE getadvocacy.id = swimsuittable.id
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

in standard sql you have to do:

```
select * 
from getadvocacy
where
    id in (select st.id from "swimsuit table" as st)
```